# Getting "No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments"

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a function for a Windows form application where I'm retrieving the list of files in a folder and I'm stripping out a "part number' contained within each file name.  I'm then adding the part number and the file name to a listbox.

Everything works fine when I use the code.

```
lstProcessedParts.Items.Add(lsPartNumber);
```

If I change the code to add the value for the listbox item, I get the error.

```
lstProcessedParts.Items.Add(lsPartNumber, lsFilename);
```

Here is my function.

```
    public void LoadPartNumberList()
    {
        string lsFilename, lsPartNumber = "";
        int liPartNumberStartPosition, liPartNumberEndPosition, liPartNumberLength = 0;

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderSelected.Text);
        foreach (string pathandfile in files)
        {
            lsFilename = Path.GetFileName(pathandfile);
            liPartNumberStartPosition = lsFilename.IndexOf("-") + 1;
            liPartNumberEndPosition = lsFilename.IndexOf("-", liPartNumberStartPosition + 5);
            liPartNumberLength = liPartNumberEndPosition - liPartNumberStartPosition;

            lsPartNumber = lsFilename.Substring(liPartNumberStartPosition, liPartNumberLength);

            lstProcessedParts.Items.Add(lsPartNumber, lsFilename);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me fix my code so this works?

Comment: Methods have specific signatures you must obey. `Add()` takes one argument. Are you expecting that code to add two items, or one item with those properties?

Comment: @Jerodev, This is not a duplicate.  For one, the question you've referenced has no answers that will help me and as well the answer tagged as correct is actually wrong... "The Method ListBox.Items.Add() takes an Object msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… ListBoxItem seems only to exist as a wpf control. Since the question was about winforms i assume that your method above is valid only for a wpf ListBox.?"

Comment: Thank you @Crowcoder.  I did not know that the method only takes one argument.  It's confusing as the error tells me "the method takes 2 arguments".  Can you suggest a way that I add the text and value to my listbox in the function that I've created?

Comment: Thanks @elgonzo, I do have to use the listbox value at a later time.  I could put both lsPartNumber + lsFilename as just the text and then strip out the lsFileName later but from a visual standpoint for the user it doesn't look good and I just want them to see the part number in the list.

Comment: I don't understand why I cannot easily add a list item with text AND value given the function I've created.

Comment: Are you expecting TWO items in your ListBox?  Then you have to use AddRange and pass your items into it as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer definitively because I can't see enough of your system, but...

If you need a different display member and value member in your Items you should add instances of a custom Type to the List and make sure you configure the display and value members accordingly.

So, if you have class:

```
class ProcessedPart
{
    public string PartNumber {get; set;}
    public string FileName {get;set;}
}
```

Now you can Add instances of `ProcessedPart` to the list:

```
lstProcessedParts.Items.Add(
    new ProcessedPart { 
        PartNumber = lsPartNumber, 
        FileName = lsFilename
    });
```

Be sure to configure the list

```
lstProcessedParts.DisplayMember = "PartNumber";
lstProcessedParts.ValueMember = "FileName";
```

... or which ever way you need it

Comment: Hey, that works!! Awesome.  Thank you @Crowcoder!  I would have NEVER of thought of doing it this way.